# Rename large folder of Jpegs

Tags: jpeg

I have a large folder of jpegs, which I would like to rename sequentially to image01.jpg, image02.jpg...image533jpg etc.

I have tried using the following

```
find ‘/myImages/‘ -maxdepth 1 -name ‘*.jpg’ | sort -n | awk 'BEGIN{ x=1 }{printf "mv \"%s\" \”/myImages/image%04d.jpg\”\n”, $0, x++ }' | bash
```

which I got from here: http://www.algissalys.com/how-to/how-to-quickly-rename-modify-and-scale-all-images-in-a-directory-using-linux

However, this is only returning

```
>
```

And then nothing happens, any suggestions would be great.

Comment: You have taken some code and removed the Imagemagick part and expect it to still work? I would look for another example and remove the Imagemagick tag from this post.

Comment: Many of the quote marks you show are "smart quotes" -- try typing over them with dumb quotes to see if that works.

Comment: You get this because you have unmatched quotes. And as @L.ScottJohnson remarks this is likely because some of your straight `"` and `'` have become a different character. If you are on Linux, in at least one file manager (Dolphin), you can select all the files, hit `F2` and be asked to provide a pattern to sequentially rename the files.

Comment: On Mac OSX I use a tool called Namechanger that I got from the App store. It works quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is with `rename` which you can install with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install rename
```

Then, you can go into your directory containing the images and run:

```
rename --dry-run -X -e '$_ = "$N"' *jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
'a.jpg' would be renamed to '1.jpg'
'article.jpg' would be renamed to '2.jpg'
'blob-0.jpg' would be renamed to '3.jpg'
'blob-1.jpg' would be renamed to '4.jpg'
'blob-2.jpg' would be renamed to '5.jpg'
'blob-3.jpg' would be renamed to '6.jpg'
```

If that looks correct, you can run it again without the `--dry-run` to actually do it, rather than just telling you what it will do.

---

If you want your names zero-padded, the easiest is to let `rename` work out how much padding you need automatically like this:

```
rename --dry-run -X -N ...01 -e '$_ = "$N"' *jpg
```

---

The benefits of using `rename` are that:

- it is simple and powerful
- it will warn you before overwriting any files
- it can do a dry run and tell you what would happen without actually doing anything

---

If you want an explanation of the command `'$_ = "$N"'` then read on...

The `rename` command is actually a Perl script, so the part I mention above is just a Perl script enclosed in single quotes. The `$N` is just a Perl variable that expands to be a sequentially increasing number. The Perl special variable `$_` is filled with the name of the current file before your little Perl script is executed, and crucially, you are expected to set it to the name you want that input file renamed as.

Comment: Hey mark, i just tried running 
```
rename  -X -e '$_ = "$N"' *jpg
```
But that has returned 
```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/rename: Argument list too long
```

That being said I am trying it on 16,000 images, possibly thats the problem?!

Comment: I'm not at a Mac to test, so please try on a COPY of your files. You should be able fo do `find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | rename -0 ALLPREVIOUSSTUFFBUTWITHOUT*.JPG`

Comment: Thanks Mark I put in find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | rename -0 -X -e '$_ = "$N"'  and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a bash script. Say you have the following in a file called `rename_images`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -a FILESERIES

FILESERIES=(`ls $1`)
NUM=${#FILESERIES[@]}
NEWNAME=$2
EXT=$3

for (( i=0; i<$NUM ; i++))
do
    FI=${FILESERIES[$i]}
    NEWFILENAME=`echo $NEWNAME$i$EXT`
    mv $FI $NEWFILENAME
done
```

To do what you need, run the script from within the folder with all the images as follows:

```
./rename_images '*.jpg' image .jpg
```

And you should be sorted.