# Why does sequentially labelling files in folder creates extra files?

Tags: shell

Currently trying to preprocess data and need to name all the image files in my folder sequentially, however when I try to do it with the code below, it  ends up producing more files that appear to be previous transformations of the images (previously inverted/cropped copies)

```sh
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.png"; done
```

I wanted the folders in my file to just label the data sequentially and not create any additional files.

The modifications to the image were made using imagemagick on Linux

The output of `ls` is as below:

```
000001560000.png~      000001900000.png~~~~   000002260000.png~
000001560000.png~~     000001900000.png~~~~~  000002260000.png~~
000001560000.png~~~    000001910000.png~      000002260000.png~~~
000001560000.png~~~~   000001910000.png~~     000002260000.png~~~~
000001560000.png~~~~~  000001910000.png~~~    000002260000.png~~~~~
000001570000.png~      000001910000.png~~~~   000002270000.png~
000001570000.png~~     000001910000.png~~~~~  000002270000.png~~
000001570000.png~~~    000001920000.png~      000002270000.png~~~
000001570000.png~~~~   000001920000.png~~     000002270000.png~~~~
000001570000.png~~~~~  000001920000.png~~~    000002270000.png~~~~~
000001580000.png~      000001920000.png~~~~   000002280000.png~
000001580000.png~~     000001920000.png~~~~~  000002280000.png~~
000001580000.png~~~    000001930000.png~      000002280000.png~~~
000001580000.png~~~~   000001930000.png~~     000002280000.png~~~~
000001580000.png~~~~~  000001930000.png~~~    000002280000.png~~~~~
000001590000.png~      000001930000.png~~~~   000002290000.png~
000001590000.png~~     000001930000.png~~~~~  000002290000.png~~
000001590000.png~~~    000001940000.png~      000002290000.png~~~
000001590000.png~~~~   000001940000.png~~     000002290000.png~~~~
000001590000.png~~~~~  000001940000.png~~~    000002290000.png~~~~~
000001600000.png~      000001940000.png~~~~   000002300000.png~
000001600000.png~~     000001940000.png~~~~~  000002300000.png~~
000001600000.png~~~    000001950000.png~      000002300000.png~~~
000001600000.png~~~~   000001950000.png~~     000002300000.png~~~~
000001600000.png~~~~~  000001950000.png~~~    000002300000.png~~~~~
000001610000.png~      000001950000.png~~~~   000002310000.png~
000001610000.png~~     000001950000.png~~~~~  000002310000.png~~
000001610000.png~~~    000001960000.png~      000002310000.png~~~
000001610000.png~~~~   000001960000.png~~     000002310000.png~~~~
000001610000.png~~~~~  000001960000.png~~~    000002310000.png~~~~~
000001620000.png~      000001960000.png~~~~   000002320000.png~
000001620000.png~~     000001960000.png~~~~~  000002320000.png~~
000001620000.png~~~    000001970000.png~      000002320000.png~~~
000001620000.png~~~~   000001970000.png~~     000002320000.png~~~~
000001620000.png~~~~~  000001970000.png~~~    000002320000.png~~~~~
000001630000.png~      000001970000.png~~~~   000002330000.png~
000001630000.png~~     000001970000.png~~~~~  000002330000.png~~
000001630000.png~~~    000001980000.png~      000002330000.png~~~
000001630000.png~~~~   000001980000.png~~     000002330000.png~~~~
000001630000.png~~~~~  000001980000.png~~~    000002330000.png~~~~~
000001640000.png~      000001980000.png~~~~   000002340000.png~
000001640000.png~~     000001980000.png~~~~~  000002340000.png~~
000001640000.png~~~    000001990000.png~      000002340000.png~~~
000001640000.png~~~~   000001990000.png~~     000002340000.png~~~~
000001640000.png~~~~~  000001990000.png~~~    000002340000.png~~~~~
000001650000.png~      000001990000.png~~~~   000002350000.png~
000001650000.png~~     000001990000.png~~~~~  000002350000.png~~
000001650000.png~~~    000002000000.png~      000002350000.png~~~
000001650000.png~~~~   000002000000.png~~     000002350000.png~~~~
000001650000.png~~~~~  000002000000.png~~~    000002350000.png~~~~~
000001660000.png~      000002000000.png~~~~   000002360000.png~
000001660000.png~~     000002000000.png~~~~~  000002360000.png~~
000001660000.png~~~    000002010000.png~      000002360000.png~~~
000001660000.png~~~~   000002010000.png~~     000002360000.png~~~~
000001660000.png~~~~~  000002010000.png~~~    000002360000.png~~~~~
000001670000.png~      000002010000.png~~~~   000002370000.png~
000001670000.png~~     000002010000.png~~~~~  000002370000.png~~
000001670000.png~~~    000002020000.png~      000002370000.png~~~
000001670000.png~~~~   000002020000.png~~     000002370000.png~~~~
000001670000.png~~~~~  000002020000.png~~~    000002370000.png~~~~~
000001680000.png~      000002020000.png~~~~   000002380000.png~
000001680000.png~~     000002020000.png~~~~~  000002380000.png~~
000001680000.png~~~    000002030000.png~      000002380000.png~~~
000001680000.png~~~~   000002030000.png~~     000002380000.png~~~~
000001680000.png~~~~~  000002030000.png~~~    000002380000.png~~~~~
000001690000.png~      000002030000.png~~~~   000002390000.png~
000001690000.png~~     000002030000.png~~~~~  000002390000.png~~
000001690000.png~~~    000002040000.png~      000002390000.png~~~
000001690000.png~~~~   000002040000.png~~     000002390000.png~~~~
000001690000.png~~~~~  000002040000.png~~~    000002390000.png~~~~~
000001700000.png~      000002040000.png~~~~   000002400000.png~
000001700000.png~~     000002040000.png~~~~~  000002400000.png~~
000001700000.png~~~    000002050000.png~      000002400000.png~~~
000001700000.png~~~~   000002050000.png~~     000002400000.png~~~~
000001700000.png~~~~~  000002050000.png~~~    000002400000.png~~~~~
000001710000.png~      000002050000.png~~~~   000002410000.png~
000001710000.png~~     000002050000.png~~~~~  000002410000.png~~
000001710000.png~~~    000002060000.png~      000002410000.png~~~
000001710000.png~~~~   000002060000.png~~     000002410000.png~~~~
000001710000.png~~~~~  000002060000.png~~~    000002410000.png~~~~~
000001720000.png~      000002060000.png~~~~   000002420000.png~
000001720000.png~~     000002060000.png~~~~~  000002420000.png~~
000001720000.png~~~    000002070000.png~      000002420000.png~~~
000001720000.png~~~~   000002070000.png~~     000002420000.png~~~~
000001720000.png~~~~~  000002070000.png~~~    000002420000.png~~~~~
000001730000.png~      000002070000.png~~~~   10.png
000001730000.png~~     000002070000.png~~~~~  11.png
000001730000.png~~~    000002080000.png~      12.png
000001730000.png~~~~   000002080000.png~~     13.png
000001730000.png~~~~~  000002080000.png~~~    14.png
000001740000.png~      000002080000.png~~~~   15.png
000001740000.png~~     000002080000.png~~~~~  16.png
000001740000.png~~~    000002090000.png~      17.png
000001740000.png~~~~   000002090000.png~~     18.png
000001740000.png~~~~~  000002090000.png~~~    19.png
000001750000.png~      000002090000.png~~~~   1.png
000001750000.png~~     000002090000.png~~~~~  20.png
000001750000.png~~~    000002100000.png~      21.png
000001750000.png~~~~   000002100000.png~~     22.png
000001750000.png~~~~~  000002100000.png~~~    23.png
000001760000.png~      000002100000.png~~~~   24.png
000001760000.png~~     000002100000.png~~~~~  25.png
000001760000.png~~~    000002110000.png~      26.png
000001760000.png~~~~   000002110000.png~~     27.png
000001760000.png~~~~~  000002110000.png~~~    28.png
000001770000.png~      000002110000.png~~~~   29.png
000001770000.png~~     000002110000.png~~~~~  2.png
000001770000.png~~~    000002120000.png~      30.png
000001770000.png~~~~   000002120000.png~~     31.png
000001770000.png~~~~~  000002120000.png~~~    32.png
000001780000.png~      000002120000.png~~~~   33.png
000001780000.png~~     000002120000.png~~~~~  34.png
000001780000.png~~~    000002130000.png~      35.png
000001780000.png~~~~   000002130000.png~~     36.png
000001780000.png~~~~~  000002130000.png~~~    37.png
000001790000.png~      000002130000.png~~~~   38.png
000001790000.png~~     000002130000.png~~~~~  39.png
000001790000.png~~~    000002140000.png~      3.png
000001790000.png~~~~   000002140000.png~~     40.png
000001790000.png~~~~~  000002140000.png~~~    41.png
000001800000.png~      000002140000.png~~~~   42.png
000001800000.png~~     000002140000.png~~~~~  43.png
000001800000.png~~~    000002150000.png~      44.png
000001800000.png~~~~   000002150000.png~~     45.png
000001800000.png~~~~~  000002150000.png~~~    46.png
000001810000.png~      000002150000.png~~~~   47.png
000001810000.png~~     000002150000.png~~~~~  48.png
000001810000.png~~~    000002160000.png~      49.png
000001810000.png~~~~   000002160000.png~~     4.png
000001810000.png~~~~~  000002160000.png~~~    50.png
000001820000.png~      000002160000.png~~~~   51.png
000001820000.png~~     000002160000.png~~~~~  52.png
000001820000.png~~~    000002170000.png~      53.png
000001820000.png~~~~   000002170000.png~~     54.png
000001820000.png~~~~~  000002170000.png~~~    55.png
000001830000.png~      000002170000.png~~~~   56.png
000001830000.png~~     000002170000.png~~~~~  57.png
000001830000.png~~~    000002180000.png~      58.png
000001830000.png~~~~   000002180000.png~~     59.png
000001830000.png~~~~~  000002180000.png~~~    5.png
000001840000.png~      000002180000.png~~~~   60.png
000001840000.png~~     000002180000.png~~~~~  61.png
000001840000.png~~~    000002190000.png~      62.png
000001840000.png~~~~   000002190000.png~~     63.png
000001840000.png~~~~~  000002190000.png~~~    64.png
000001850000.png~      000002190000.png~~~~   65.png
000001850000.png~~     000002190000.png~~~~~  66.png
000001850000.png~~~    000002200000.png~      67.png
000001850000.png~~~~   000002200000.png~~     68.png
000001850000.png~~~~~  000002200000.png~~~    69.png
000001860000.png~      000002200000.png~~~~   6.png
000001860000.png~~     000002200000.png~~~~~  70.png
000001860000.png~~~    000002210000.png~      71.png
000001860000.png~~~~   000002220000.png~      72.png
000001860000.png~~~~~  000002220000.png~~     73.png
000001870000.png~      000002220000.png~~~    74.png
000001870000.png~~     000002220000.png~~~~   75.png
000001870000.png~~~    000002220000.png~~~~~  76.png
000001870000.png~~~~   000002230000.png~      77.png
000001870000.png~~~~~  000002230000.png~~     78.png
000001880000.png~      000002230000.png~~~    79.png
000001880000.png~~     000002230000.png~~~~   7.png
000001880000.png~~~    000002230000.png~~~~~  80.png
000001880000.png~~~~   000002240000.png~      81.png
000001880000.png~~~~~  000002240000.png~~     82.png
000001890000.png~      000002240000.png~~~    83.png
000001890000.png~~     000002240000.png~~~~   84.png
000001890000.png~~~    000002240000.png~~~~~  85.png
000001890000.png~~~~   000002250000.png~      86.png
000001890000.png~~~~~  000002250000.png~~     8.png
000001900000.png~      000002250000.png~~~    9.png
000001900000.png~~     000002250000.png~~~~
000001900000.png~~~    000002250000.png~~~~~
```

The output of the second `ls` is:

```
100.png  148.png  196.png  244.png  292.png  340.png  388.png  436.png  484.png
101.png  149.png  197.png  245.png  293.png  341.png  389.png  437.png  485.png
102.png  150.png  198.png  246.png  294.png  342.png  390.png  438.png  486.png
103.png  151.png  199.png  247.png  295.png  343.png  391.png  439.png  487.png
104.png  152.png  200.png  248.png  296.png  344.png  392.png  440.png  488.png
105.png  153.png  201.png  249.png  297.png  345.png  393.png  441.png  489.png
106.png  154.png  202.png  250.png  298.png  346.png  394.png  442.png  490.png
107.png  155.png  203.png  251.png  299.png  347.png  395.png  443.png  491.png
108.png  156.png  204.png  252.png  300.png  348.png  396.png  444.png  492.png
109.png  157.png  205.png  253.png  301.png  349.png  397.png  445.png  493.png
110.png  158.png  206.png  254.png  302.png  350.png  398.png  446.png  494.png
111.png  159.png  207.png  255.png  303.png  351.png  399.png  447.png  495.png
112.png  160.png  208.png  256.png  304.png  352.png  400.png  448.png  496.png
113.png  161.png  209.png  257.png  305.png  353.png  401.png  449.png  497.png
114.png  162.png  210.png  258.png  306.png  354.png  402.png  450.png  498.png
115.png  163.png  211.png  259.png  307.png  355.png  403.png  451.png  499.png
116.png  164.png  212.png  260.png  308.png  356.png  404.png  452.png  500.png
117.png  165.png  213.png  261.png  309.png  357.png  405.png  453.png  501.png
118.png  166.png  214.png  262.png  310.png  358.png  406.png  454.png  502.png
119.png  167.png  215.png  263.png  311.png  359.png  407.png  455.png  503.png
120.png  168.png  216.png  264.png  312.png  360.png  408.png  456.png  504.png
121.png  169.png  217.png  265.png  313.png  361.png  409.png  457.png  505.png
122.png  170.png  218.png  266.png  314.png  362.png  410.png  458.png  506.png
123.png  171.png  219.png  267.png  315.png  363.png  411.png  459.png  507.png
124.png  172.png  220.png  268.png  316.png  364.png  412.png  460.png  508.png
125.png  173.png  221.png  269.png  317.png  365.png  413.png  461.png  509.png
126.png  174.png  222.png  270.png  318.png  366.png  414.png  462.png  510.png
127.png  175.png  223.png  271.png  319.png  367.png  415.png  463.png  511.png
128.png  176.png  224.png  272.png  320.png  368.png  416.png  464.png  512.png
129.png  177.png  225.png  273.png  321.png  369.png  417.png  465.png  513.png
130.png  178.png  226.png  274.png  322.png  370.png  418.png  466.png  514.png
131.png  179.png  227.png  275.png  323.png  371.png  419.png  467.png  515.png
132.png  180.png  228.png  276.png  324.png  372.png  420.png  468.png  516.png
133.png  181.png  229.png  277.png  325.png  373.png  421.png  469.png  517.png
134.png  182.png  230.png  278.png  326.png  374.png  422.png  470.png  87.png
135.png  183.png  231.png  279.png  327.png  375.png  423.png  471.png  88.png
136.png  184.png  232.png  280.png  328.png  376.png  424.png  472.png  89.png
137.png  185.png  233.png  281.png  329.png  377.png  425.png  473.png  90.png
138.png  186.png  234.png  282.png  330.png  378.png  426.png  474.png  91.png
139.png  187.png  235.png  283.png  331.png  379.png  427.png  475.png  92.png
140.png  188.png  236.png  284.png  332.png  380.png  428.png  476.png  93.png
141.png  189.png  237.png  285.png  333.png  381.png  429.png  477.png  94.png
142.png  190.png  238.png  286.png  334.png  382.png  430.png  478.png  95.png
143.png  191.png  239.png  287.png  335.png  383.png  431.png  479.png  96.png
144.png  192.png  240.png  288.png  336.png  384.png  432.png  480.png  97.png
145.png  193.png  241.png  289.png  337.png  385.png  433.png  481.png  98.png
146.png  194.png  242.png  290.png  338.png  386.png  434.png  482.png  99.png
147.png  195.png  243.png  291.png  339.png  387.png  435.png  483.png
```

Comment: Are you saying that you believe this command is inverting and cropping images? I really don't think that's the case

Comment: I mean when I preprocessed the data, I had to invert colours/crop etc. using imagemagick. However once I run that piece of code to rename all the files, it seems to also bring back past versions (for example I'll see the original, as well as an inverted version, a recoloured one, and basically one for each step I took in the preprocessing step) @thatotherguy

Comment: Cropping in imagemagick can create multiple crops. Not sure that is the case here. But you did not show any ImageMagick commands. Also did you write over the input image with the cropped output? Are you sure, the original is not still in your directory or some other directory. Did you write your output to a new directory rather than write over the old one? Your comment says you made 'copies'. That would imply you kept the original.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've been using mogrify in the same folder, not creating a new folder with my changes. @fmw42

Comment: Can you please update with actual and expected output? For example, post the output of `ls`, followed by `( set -x; ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.png"; done )` to show a debug trace of the moves, followed by another `ls`, and then showing how there are now more files than you expected. Make especially sure it's real command output (i.e. don't fabricate something to show what you mean)

Comment: `@Brian Diep`. Look in the folder before and after you use mogrify to see if you have the right number of images and if not what they are? Post your mogrify command. When you create your output in mogrify, are you changing the format? If so, it will leave the old image and create a new one. So you will have both suffixes.

Comment: `cat -n` - consider the more idiomatic utility called `nl` (literally for 'Number Lines')

Comment: @fmw42 in order I've applied: (`mogrify convert -format JPG *png`) , (`mogrify -crop 442x605 *.png`), (`mogrify convert -fuzz 25% -fill white -opaque "#FF33FF" *.png`), (`mogrify convert -negate -threshold 0 *.png`) and (`mogrify convert -negate *.png`). Then I ran the loop above. Throughout all those steps the number of images in the folder is the same throughout, after numerating it goes from 86 (the correct number) to 2500+

Comment: Maybe a little late, but here's how to sequentially number images easily... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56579912/2836621

Comment: `@Brian Diep` Your syntax for mogrify is wrong. In ImageMagick 7, it should be magick mogrify .... Not mogrify convert. You have changed pngs to jpgs. So you will have both the original PNG file and the new JPG files in your directory after the mogrify command. If you do -crop WxH and not WxH+Xoff+Yoff, you will get multiple crop pieces from the output. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile. Every time you do a new mogrify on the old directory, you will process each file in the directory. If you change formats, then the number will double for each time, since the old format is kept

Comment: `@Brian Diep` The best thing I can suggest is not to use mogrify. But to write a script loop over the directory and use magick (replacement in IM 7 for IM 6 convert) to do all the processing. Then you can number the outputs in sequence with the loop. If you stay with mogrify, then you can do all the processing in one mogrify command. No need for multiple mogrifies.