# search and rename and mv all files from directories and subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, unix, mv

i have a lot of files  `30k directories, 21k files`
inside direrctories and  subdirerctories of `txt` files with  the same name

```
     ├── cases__in_africa
        │   ├── 2020/10/01.txt
        │   ├── 2020/10/02.txt
        │   ├── 2020/10/03.txt
        │   └── 2020/10/04.txt
        ├── death_in_africa
        │   ├── 2020/10/01.txt
        │   ├── 2020/10/02.txt
        │   ├── 2020/10/03.txt
        │   └── 2020/10/04.txt
2926 directories, 21646 files
```

i want to search for  all files inside a lot of subdirerctories and than rename them to other unique name to move them to other directory.

This command not showing  the duplicate files

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec mv  "{}" ./all \;
```

Comment: Use `mv -v` instead of `mv` and consider writing a [Python](http://python.org/) or a [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) script. Of course, you'll need to read documentation before doing that. See also [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) and [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)

Comment: mv: './all/01.txt' and './all/01.txt' are the same file 
the same problem

Comment: How do you want to rename `2020/10/01.txt`?

Comment: as i  describe search and rename theme  with unique  name the 21646 files from 2926 directories and then move them to  another  place so i did a search and  I can move but when i  move it show me only 164 files from  21k  files

Comment: That is because all files named, e.g. `2020/10/04.txt` overwrite files of the same name moved to the `./all` directory. You need to append something to each file name that will make them unique, e.g. `cases__in_africa_2020/10/04.txt` of take a hash of the file, use milliseconds since epoch or something.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: the out that  i want  is the entire 21k files but ii have  only 164 file days  
[all/0[1...30}txt]  and other same files names

Comment: There is a simple solution using `rename` here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56579912/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find this helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003554/how-to-rename-all-jpg-files-in-all-subdirs-wich-contains-dash-in-linux

```
find -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'mv  "{}" "$RANDOM.txt"' \;
```

Comment: You should bear in mind that RANDOM only gives 32,768 different numbers so you'll almost certainly get collisions with calling it 21,000 times.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for sequential naming, you can do it like this with the assumption that the target directory `all` does exist in your current directory.:

```sh
for file in $(find ./ -type f -name "*.txt"); do ((count++)) ; mv $file ./all/${count}.txt; done
```